# AC sources in DC analysis

Tags: ac, dc, differential-amplifier

Can I ground AC voltage sources when I do DC analysis of differential amplifier with BJT and current mirrors circuits?

Comment: Only if they, themselves, don't have DC.

Comment: If you want to ignore a source for a particular analysis, you typically "zero" it (set it to 0 V or 0 A) rather than ground it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing DC analysis, if the AC sources don't have a DC component themselves, it is possible to analyze the circuit ignoring the AC sources.